# Kendo Filter is not applying on if we have binded two separate column values in Single column on UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo MVC and I have bound first name and last name column values in a single column name as PatientName. But when I tried to apply filter on Patient Name then I am getting empty Result Set.

In controller:

```
PatientName = a.LastName + "," + a.FirstName,
```

In the UI

```
columns.Bound(c => c.PatientName);
```

Comment: Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a filter in the UI causes a callback to the data source Read endpoint, with the filter parameters passed along.  The filter is using a column, patient name, that is probably not present in the model set up for the data base context.  The Kendo.Mvc classes automatically handle applying the filter parameters to the back end database query during *queryable*`.ToDataSourceResult(request)`.

Set a break point in the Read routine and examine the incoming values.

Open the browser tools and examine the data sent and response received when filtering.